# Absolute positioning of DIV over embedded document

Tags: html, css, overlay

I tried to find a similar question on StackOverflow but could only find ones related to Flash objects.

I'm trying to position a div on top of an embedded object using the following code with all three tags - iframe, object & embed:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.overlay {
  background:#FFFFFF;
  border:1px solid #000000;
  padding:30px;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:50%;
  width:100px;
  margin-left:-50px;
  z-index:99;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align:center;
  background:#F00;
  padding:20px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="overlay">Overlay DIV</div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <embed width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.foxitsoftware.com/resources/pdf/Datasheet_Reader.pdf" frameborder="0"></embed>
        <!--<object width="100%" height="100%" data="http://www.foxitsoftware.com/resources/pdf/Datasheet_Reader.pdf" frameborder="0"></object>-->
        <!--<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.foxitsoftware.com/resources/pdf/Datasheet_Reader.pdf" frameborder="0"></iframe>-->

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It works great in latest versions of Firefox and Chrome but not IE9. I need it to work in IE8 and higher.

Is it possible to do at all in IE8+?

Answer (score 0):

You can put an iframe under the overlay.
http://jsfiddle.net/emn178/64XeK/

```
<style>
iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
</style>

<div class="overlay">Overlay DIV<iframe frameborder="0"></iframe></div>
```

This is the best way I found.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but still no luck in IE. Works fine in Firefox as my original code does.